# white bar on the top of storyboard on Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

[theres white bar on the top that covers my button, how I can get rid of it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN1oP.jpg)

Comment: Try it in the simulator, that white bar indicates that your view controller is nested inside something. (maybe a navigation controller?) It shouldn't show when running your app.

Comment: Can you post your storyboard for this view controller and also detailed elements in Xcode's Document Outline window please?

Comment: thanks, I have made it when I get back to view controller and choose some property I forgot as None

Answer (score 0):

Go into Attributes inspector, and within Top Bar, select none.